# Orchard CMS - migrations - UTF8 characters

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a custom content type in orchard module migrations. The code is as follows:

```
   ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Branch",
            cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("Branch")
                .WithPart("AutoroutePart")
                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithPart("AddressPart")
                .DisplayedAs("Pobočka")
                .Creatable()
                .Listable()
        );
```

If I create it like this, the content type has an ugly rhombus instead of my c with a hook. If I specify the name in Admin, it works fine. I guess I need to find out how orchard saves the DisplayedAs property into database, maybe format it correctly?

Comment: Hello, thanks for a reply, I will, but I'm not sure how, is this the right place?

https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardDoc/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: No, this is: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/new